# Reading data from hdf5 file to plot a graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, external-files, database

Normally when one wishes to to plot some data from a file (.txt, .csv or the like), one would do something like

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot table {data.txt};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and get something like
[image]

Now, if instead my data was in a hdf5 file (say `data.h5`) with the x and y data in the fields `/xdata` and `/ydata` respectivly, is there any way for me to get the data out from LaTeX, or do i need a third party thing (like a script) to repackage the data?

Here data.txt was:

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 8
9 9
```

Comment: A.h5 could hypothetically be anywhere in the real or unreal universe, it is a structure that is reputedly best accessed through h5py which states "You’ll need HDF5 installed, which can be a pain". IS there a reason you need some h5 output that is not in CSV or other two column export / expert ? format.

Comment: Simply opening a.H5 could as with any portable document format like PDF contain any thing from textual columns or a a graph through media etc here starts an **image.h5** ‰HDF  ÿÿmÿÿ`ˆ¨ˆ¨TREEÿÿÿÿ0HEAPX0Èimage8bitpaletteimage24bitpixel( (,,xX`ÀÔ™sN (CLASSIMAGE 0IMAGE_VERSION1.2SNOD ( ÐàH 8IMAGE_SUBCLASSIMAGE_INDEXED( Ý™sN (CLASSPALETTE 0 PAL_VERSION1.2 (PALETTEÐ 8•ã•ã}l˜ à]Œ™sN (CLASSIMAGE 0IMAGE_VERSION1.2

Comment: There is a Lua-library for reading HDF5 (https://colberg.org/lua-hdf5/), perhaps you could use that with LuaTeX to access the data.

Comment: @KJO, The only reason is to skip conversion between the formats (so lazyness). And because it would be cool ;-)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Cool sstuff ;-)

Comment: Ok it would be cool to get latex to rebuild itself from a PDF but we know that's fraught with too many hurdles unless the pdf is a plain text rendition of its own  .tex file --- thus getting plain XY data from a virtual encrypted compressed binary blob, is very possible if H5 places in mid page in an comma separated output, much simpler to hit the export csv  button,

Comment: @KJO you could just say; no it's not possible. What's wrong with asking a question?

Comment: @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen, It **is probably** possible, but is it worth the long haul ? If I understand your wish correctly you want \latex to read data.h5 this may be possible if data.h5 is flushed out to drive as a given well structured ascii stream of plain data.. however we usually output such columns of data from excel etc. in a text format such as columns.csv for simplicity, hence my view its best to use HDF5 to output TeX compatible data

Comment: I wonder if something similar to what `minted` does could be used? Run an external tool (a python script that reads the needed portion of the HDF5 file) that converts to the desired output format, and caches it for later rendering? If I wasn't neck deep in other projects I'd maybe look at writing a LaTeX package similar to minted to work with h5py.